# Issue with pexpect script

Tags: pexpect

I was working in a pexpect script in order to establish a ftp connection, I followed the following approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('ftp mydomanin.com.mx')
child.expect ('.*[Nn]ame.*: ')
child.sendline ('user')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline ('mypassword')
child.interact()
```

This works well the connection is establish, but the problem comes when I add the following line to the script

```
child.expect ('ftp> ', )
```

The script doesn't do nothing if I add this line, I don't know what is the reason for this i would appreciate any help whit this issue.

Comment: Because it isn't matching, for whatever reason.

Comment: Why not post a screenshot, logs, or actual output from the client process? Nobody can help you without those things.

Comment: Try to create ftp connection directly and check if everything works. Maybe user name or password is faulty or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling `child.interact()` then you need not call `child.expect()` afterwards. (Assuming you are calling it afterwards).

> [Interact gives control of the child process to the interactive user (the human at the keyboard). Keystrokes are sent to the child process, and the stdout and stderr output of the child process is printed. This simply echos the child stdout and child stderr to the real stdout and it echos the real stdin to the child stdin. When the user types the escape_character this method will stop. The default for escape_character is ^]](http://www.bx.psu.edu/~nate/pexpect/pexpect.html)

You are expecting ftp prompt `ftp>` from your script. It will automatically appear after the interact call. If you are calling `child.expect('ftp>')` before the call to interact then hitting return will get the desired prompt. Expecting 'ftp>' is obsolete in this case however.